# Persistir upload ao navegar pelo site

Tags: javascript, html

É possível realizar um `upload` de arquivos e habilitar a navegação pelo site mantendo ele em carregando em background?

O normal ao enviar um arquivo é perder o progresso ao sair da página atual.
Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de manter a navegação mas o upload não se perder, é possível?

Comment: Sair da página (= carregar um novo endereço) irá interromper o upload. Mas se sua navegação for toda por Ajax, é possível permitir que a navegação dentro do site possa continuar ativa durante o upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for uma Single Page Application sim, pois a navegação não faz uma nova requisição para uma nova página, mas apenas manipula o DOM para mudar os elementos HTML que são exibidos.
Veja mais em: https://blog.codecasts.com.br/single-page-applications-onde-vivem-e-o-que-comem-4fc9a44f3de

Caso contrário você teria que "simular" uma SPA, implementando e invocando a função que faz o upload no maior contexto possível e deixando seu usuário "navegar" sem mudar o pathname, apenas exibindo outros elementos HTML de acordo com a interação dele.